# I need help getting my slide to top accordion to stop below my fixed top header

Tags: javascript, css, accordion

I think this is a `css` issue, but it could be an issue with the `js`. When my accordion links are clicked on, they are supposed to open and slide to the top of the page - which they do. However, I have a fixed top header and they are sliding up behind that. I need it to stop about 60px lower on the page so that it is visible.

http://imip.rvadv.com/index3.html

http://jsfiddle.net/imakeitpretty/ruwjn/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

On line 102 of `jquery.accordion.js` an offset value is set for each item in the accordian. You can simply subtract a static number (you suggested 60px) to that value for each number to change how far the document will scroll. To do it elegantly, I would pass it as another option which you can then access from within the script by doing something like this (assuming you name your option `scrollOffset`:

```
_saveDimValues    : function() {
    scrollOffset = this.options.scrollOffset;
    this.$items.each( function() {

      var $item   = $(this);

      $item.data({
        originalHeight  : $item.find('a:first').height(),
        offsetTop   : $item.offset().top - scrollOffset
      });

    });

},
```

http://jsfiddle.net/ruwjn/7/

Comment: Perfect! This looks great thanks! One more question: When I click on the 2nd accordion link, it opens up properly, then when I click it a second time to close it, it doesn't close "all the way", it leaves added space between that accordion link and the third link. Did that make sense at all? http://imip.rvadv.com/index3.html#aboutme

Comment: I haven't tested it, but if I had to guess it has to do with line 149. This is where it resets the item's height, and it adds `$this.find('div.st-content').outerHeight( true )`... not entirely sure what that's about you can try removing it but I'd trace it back a little further.

Comment: :( I know nothing about `js`. I see where you are talking about but I don't know how to rewrite that to get it to behave differently.

Comment: Try removing the `+ $this.find('div.st-content').outerHeight( true )` from that line. So it would be `$this.css( 'height', $this.data( 'originalHeight' ) )`